# wordpress new theme custom otf font

Tags: css, wordpress, fonts, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm trying to include the "Aribau Grotesk" font to a new theme, I have a folder with the .otf files, try to include them from style.css but it does not seem to work, any suggestion will be much appreciated.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Aribau Grotesk';
    src: url(/fonts/Aribau_Grotesk/Aribau Grotesk.otf);  
}

body{
    font-family: 'Aribau Grotesk';
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this website https://transfonter.org/
it creates webfonts for u with the css includes